# Add character inside AlpineJS x-text

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using AlpineJS I have the following code:

```
<span class="value" x-text="calculate"></span>
```

The function `calculate` returns a number.

How to inside the x-text add the character "€" after the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```html
<span class="value" x-text="calculate() + '€'"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
<span class="value" x-text="'€' + calculate"></span>
```